# Get data from mysql database in clojure

Tags: mysql, select, text, clojure

I am trying to get some text from a database and use it in a function in clojure.

```
(defn getSelectedText [id]
    (j/query mysql-db
    ["select timesRead, text from news where id=?" id]))
```

When I `println` this it shows

```
( {:timesRead 6, :text "Some text"})
```

When I try `get` to get the text from this it just doesn't work.

Do you have any idea how to change the `getSelectedText` function to get the text I need?

Comment: Isn't it a sequence that consists of one element?

Comment: Yup, zerkms is right, you're trying to do a `get` on a collection of one map (record).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
(defn getSelectedText [id]
  (:text
    (first
      (j/query mysql-db
      ["select timesRead, text from news where id=?" id]))))
```

you're getting back a sequences of maps. `first` gives you the first item in the sequence, so then you have a map. `:text` says 'give me the value assigned to the :text key in the map'.

A note about retrieving values out of maps: what's interesting is that you can actually do either

```
(:text my-map)
```

or

```
(my-map :text)
```

(also, the first form works with keywords (which start with the colon `:`) but not with keys that are strings; the jdbc library generally keywordizes column names for convenience)

Answer (score 1):

When the resultset contains more records, you might want to take a look at the `:row-fn` and `:result-set-fn` parameters of `clojure.java.jdbc/query` to prevent copying all the of resultset before the connection is closed.

Processing inside the scope of the query fn / connection in this case would be done like

```
(defn getSelectedText [id]
  (j/query mysql-db
           ["select timesRead, text from news where id=?" id]
           :result-set-fn first  ;this fn should NOT be lazy
           :row-fn :text))
```

Comment: i agree that using `:result-set-fn` is a good practice for large datasets. but  `query` does actually return a fully realized sequence, so it's safe to process the results outside/afterward if desired.

Comment: Of course, default result-set-fn is doall. Will edit ehen back at a real kb